# Is there an average year of weather across the United States?

Tags: meteorology, climate, united-states

I am interested in which year has the best representation of average weather across a large area, the contiguous USA. This is challenging since what was average in the Midwest might have been unusual in the Southeast at that time. Still I think there is a year that is closest to 'normal' for the largest portion of the USA compared to other years.

Am I wrong to think one year could represent an average for such a large area? If needing to pick a year most representative across the contiguous USA, how would one identify the best year, say from 1990-2020? Is there an easy place to lookup this kind of climate information, or what calculations would need to be done?

Comment: https://phys.org/news/2015-02-years-above-average-temperatures-climate.html has a good description on using the global average for 1901-2000 to determine every month in the last 30 year (now 35 years) was warmer than that average. Your first step is determining what you want to use for a comparative average.

Comment: A year in which every place in the US experienced average weather every day would be an extremely abnormal year.

Comment: @DavidHammen The representative average year might not be normal, but it would be helpful to have a single year to compare different places in the U.S. against. Otherwise, for most years that are not a good representative of the broad U.S. having average weather, an analysis in one place may be assessing conditions in a particularly dry or hot year whereas the same year in another place may have represented that places average. Therefore I'm looking for a year best representing average conditions across the U.S. Part of the challenge is how to begin identifying avg for such a large area.